# Does Android support click events in its WebView?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, sencha-touch

I'm using PhoneGap and Sencha Touch to display a form. I'm using an image as the button to submit it:

```
<img id='submit' src='button.png' />
```

I'd like to then listen to it be clicked and validate the form. If I try the following it never seems to fire:

```
Ext.get('submit').on('click', validateFn);
```

Am I missing something obvious? Should I use `<input type="image" ... />`?

**Update:** For future viewers of this question it is worth noting that inconsistent click handling seems to be a bug or series of bugs in Android's WebView. There are [several](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2887) [unresolved](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8484) [bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8620) on this topic.

Comment: Should the Ext.get('submit') be Ext.get('#submit') or something like that? I am not totally familiar with Ext.

Comment: I'm not either. I'll check, because that would make me feel very dumb (but very happy) if that's the case.

Comment: Actually, only the format _without_ the `#` is supported. Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it do accept click events

Check this link and sample out

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html

Comment: Thanks. It looks like my problem was transient and so probably not specifically related to generic click events in WebView.

Comment: That link is no longer valid.